# Aplicar "datepicker" em elemento após chamada angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directives

Estou tendo um problema, ao carregar um bloco HTML da página via angular, os elementos que tem a classe ".datepicker", ativam o jquery do plugin "datepicker", porém, pelo que notei, a ação que faz o bind deste bloco, está ocorrendo depois do carregamento dos elementos.

Pesquisei a respeito, comentaram sobre o uso de $watch e $on, estamos chamando o HTML / JS do datepicker, da seguinte forma:

Chamada do datepicker:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker():
```

Elemento ( Este elemento está dentro de um ng-controller e um ng-repeat ):

```
<input class="datepicker"  />
```

Este input está dentro de um "ng-controller" e em um "ng-repeat", não está sendo usado uma diretiva, existe alguma forma de disparar um evento após o carregamento do bloco?

Answer (score 1):

@helderburato

Tente fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
$(document).on('click','.datepicker',function() {
   $(this).datepicker();
}
```

e veja se resolve seus problemas :)

Comment: Na realidade, o problema está sendo, que este input, esta dentro de um NG-REPEAT, e simplesmente, não funciona o datepicker dentro dele.

Comment: Então dê uma olhada nesse link em inglês do SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099267/angular-ui-datepicker-in-ng-repeat-works-only-for-first-block

Comment: @helderburato nem a maneira q falei, nem o link não lhe serviram de nada? Caso tenha resolvido, poste uma resposta a sua pergunta para servir de base para outros futuramente.

Answer (score 0):

Olá para poder integrar o Datepicker no AngularJS a melhor saída é criando uma directive personalizada.

No exemplo abaixo eu criei uma app angular e inclui uma directive de nome "incluiDatepicker" poderia ser qualquer nome. O importante é a chamada no input.
o nome fica separado por "-" ex. inclui-datapicker como atributo da tag input. se a directive com um nome minhaDirAng = minha-dir-ang.

```
//
app.directive('incluiDatepicker', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem) {
           elem.datepicker();
        }
    };
    });

<input type="text" id="nomedoId" incluir-datepicker>
```

Eu usei isso ai funcionou perfeitamente.
o legal que você me precisa ficar chamando o datepicker.

Comment: Se sua resposta realmente resolve o problema proposto, se possível, elabore-a melhor, afinal a dúvida do OP hoje, se solucionada com sua resposta, evitaria duplicidade de conteúdo amanhã. ;)

Answer (score 0):

No seu HTML:

use ng-init!

```
<input ... class="datepicker" ng-init="initDatepicker()">
```

E no seu AngularJs:

```
$scope.initDatepicker = function() {
    $('.datepicker').pickadate({ 
        selectMonths: true, 
        selectYears: 15
    });
}
```